# "The session was closed before message transfer was complete" with WCF reliable sessions

Tags: wcf

I've got a WCF service that uses reliable sessions. In my tests, I tend to open a channel, call a method and then close the channel.

I often get a `The session was closed before message transfer was complete.` exception during `Close()`.

Given that my method is synchronous, the message transfer should be complete. If it's reliable sessions causing this problem (because it's still doing something under the hood), surely it's responsible for either blocking my `Close()` call, or for giving up without throwing an exception?

How do I avoid this exception?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should find what caused the connection close. Add diagnostics to you server and client config files by using the WCF Service Configuration Editor.

Repro the error and open your logs in the viewer. You will probably find that the message was to large at the serverside.

Comment: I caused the `Close()` -- I called it at the end of my test.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the solution was to change operation contract in my interface definition by marking called method as **IsOneWay=false** which is default setting.

Make sure you haven't change your operation contract for your method to

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to consider is specifying a timeout value in your call to Close() to allow more time for graceful closing. This can spare you many problems. (Although I agree that finding the cause and trying to prevent it is also important).